# New browser window does not contain URL bar - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm quite new to Visual Studio '17.
When I run my project, it opens in a new chrome window. I know that its for enabling JS/TS debugging.
However, the new chrome window is not showing any url bar, and its happening from very recently.
A solution will be very helpful.

Thanks.